# Sockets and data transfer formats

Tags: c#, sockets, theory

i'm new in Sockets, and i have a some theoretical questions regarding Client <-> Server communication.

Question is about message type and format.

1. If i will use a string as byte[] with delimeters as a message, for all client-server operations, is it a good practice for a high load project? 
   Example:
   "CMSG_AUTH:Login:Password"
2. I've heard, that somebody using opcodes as server return command. Should i use string and opcodes in tandem? And how? Which design patterns would be good to learn, for a internal server architecture?
   (I know, it's a stupid question, but i really interested in server development, and it's my dream to write good, scalable server application). I don't want to use WCF, i want to make it from scratch, just to understand how it works.

Comment: Are you thinking TCP or UDP? A common beginner mistake is to not realise that TCP sockets just offer the abstraction of "a stream of bytes" - if you want *messages*, it's up to you to implement those on top of the TCP abstraction.

Comment: Yes, okay. So if you want messages, you have to implement them. A call to `Receive` might receive *part* of a message. Or the end of one message, another complete message and the start of a third. Or any other combination you can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an established format to serialize messages from client and server. The counterpart can deserialize by using the same format.

Examples for formats are JSON, xml (uses strings) or protobuf (binary).

Define classes for the information that you want to transmit between client and server:

```
   class LoginDto
   {
       string UserName {get;set;}
       string Secret{get;set;}
   }
```

If you stick to an established format it is very easy to serialize an instance of such a class to be transmitted over the wire.

Look for `DataContractSerializer`, `JSON.Net` or `Protobuf-net` for implementations of XML, JSON and protobuf serializers.